# Displaying error messages in jsp without reloading page

Tags: validation, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, error-handling

I have a program using jsp and servlets that checks the database for an email address. First the jsp page sends the email to the doPost method of the servlet, then the servlet checks the database, if email exists I use request.setAttribute set a success message and then forward it to the same jsp page, if it doesn't exist it forwards an error message.
The problem i am facing is that it refreshes the jsp page, whereas when I used php for another program i was able to display just by echo without refreshing the entire page.

Comment: You need to look into ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JQuery [Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) request to do this:

Servlet:

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write("good email or not?");
```

Jsp:

```
$('#emailButton').click(function() {
   $.post('mySevlet', function(responseText) { 
       if (responseText == 'good'){
          $('#statusDiv').text('you are good to go.');         
       }else{
          $('#statusDiv').text('Stop Righ there!');   
       }
   });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the example and pointing me in the right direction. I was very confused whether to use AJAX or Spring or Hibernate.